# exec as a pipeline component

Tags: bash, docker, signaling

For our application running inside a container it is preferable that it receives a SIGTERM when the container is being (gracefully) shutdown. At the same time, we want it's output to go to a log file.

In the startscript of our docker container, we had therefore been using bash's `exec` similar to this

```
exec command someParam >> stdout.log
```

That worked just fine, `command` replaced the shell that had been the container's root process and would receive the SIGTERM.

Since the application tends to log a lot, we decided to add log rotation by using Apache's `rotatelogs` tool, i.e.

```
exec command | rotatelogs -n 10 stdout.log 10M
```

Alas, it seems that by using the pipe, exec can no longer have `command` replace the shell. When looking at the processes in the running container with `pstree -p`, it now looks like this

```
mycontainer@/#pstree -p
start.sh(1)-+-command(118)
            `-rotatelogs(119)
```

So bash remains the root process, and does not pass the SIGTERM on to command.
Before stumbling upon exec, I had found an approach that installs a signal handler into the bash script, which would then itself send a SIGTERM to the `command` process using `kill`. However, this became really convoluted, getting the PID was also not always straightforward, and I would like to preserve the convenience of exec when it comes to signal handling *and* get piping for log rotation.
Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you do the log management outside of Docker: have the process write to its stdout as normal, and either `docker run > container.log` or [configure an alternate Docker logging system](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/)?  That avoids this problem and the need to have log-management tools inside the container (and avoids the question of which filesystem is getting the collected logs).

Comment: @DavidMaze We are actually putting all logs of all our containers in a folder that is a network share to allow easy collecting of all logs on customer clusters without a sophisticated log handling stack (EFK or whatever). The applications write a lot of other log files (out of historic reasons), so we need that anyway. We often either only get those files (and nothing on stdout/err) or only stdout/err.
I should mention that we mainly focus on K8s these days.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want

```sh
exec sh -c 'command | rotatelogs -n 10 stdout.log 10M'
```

Comment: Hi @glenn, I gave this a try (actually using "bash -c" instead of "sh -c"... but it is giving me the same pstree with non-working signal handling as without, i.e., bash being root with command and rotatelogs as its children.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this by using process substitution. For your specific case the following may work.

```sh
exec command > >(rotatelogs -n 10 stdout.log 10M)
```

To reproduce the scenario I built this simple Dockerfile

```
FROM perl
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

# The following will gracefully terminate upon docker stop
CMD exec perl -e '$SIG{TERM} = sub { $|++; print "Caught a sigterm!\n"; sleep(5); die "is the end!" }; sleep(30);' 2>&1 > >(tee /my_log)

# The following won't gracefully terminate upon docker stop
#CMD exec perl -e '$SIG{TERM} = sub { $|++; print "Caught a sigterm!\n"; sleep(5); die "is the end!" }; sleep(30);' 2>&1 | tee /my_log
```

Build `docker build -f Dockerfile.meu -t test .`

Run `docker run --name test --rm -ti test`

Stop it `docker stop test`

Output:

```
Caught a sigterm!
is the end! at -e line 1.
```